# Isothermal parameterization, Inverse of the Gauss Map

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, surfaces, minimal-surfaces

This problem is from Do Carmo's Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces. It is question 13 from chapter 3.5, to be specific.

Suppose that S is a minimal surface without any umbilical points (that is to say that $k_1 = -k_2$ everywhere). Let $\bar{x}$ be a parameterization of the unit sphere by stereograhic projection, and consider a neighborhood $V$ of a point $p$ on the surface so that the Gauss map $N: S \rightarrow S^2$ restricted to the neighborhood $V$ is a diffeomorphism.

The question is to show that the parameterization $q= N^{-1}$ o $\bar x$ is isothermal, meaning that $<q_u, q_u > = <q_v, q_v>$ and $<q_u,q_v> = 0$ everywhere on $S$.

Now when I saw this question, my first instinct was to try to verify that $q$ was isothermal directly by computing the parameterization in some kind of coordinates directly. I know that stereographic projection is given by the formulas:

$$ x= \frac {4u}{u^2+v^2+4}$$

$$ y = \frac {4v}{u^2+v^2+4}$$

$$ z = \frac {2(u^2+v^2)}{u^2+v^2+4} $$

I figured with this information, maybe I could find a way to write down what $q$ is in terms of $u$ and $v$ and take partials. The problem is that I don't know how to write down anything about $N^{-1}$. Like when working with $N$, I can say that a point on a surface $S$ goes to it's normal, which is something that I can compute in terms of cross products of partial derivatives of a parameterization of the surface.

Is this method workable? I don't know if I can proceed any further this way. If not, what can I do to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Stereographic projection is conformal and you can also show the Gauss map is conformal for a minimal surface.

This is not very hard; simply assume $\langle dN_p(t_1),dN_p(t_2)\rangle=\lambda(p)\langle t_1,t_2\rangle \forall t_1,t_2 \in T_pS$ and then take the basis of $T_pS$ consisting of the principal directions of the gauss map. A quick bit of algebra will show that the principal curvatures satisfy $k_1=-k_2$.

Hence the parameterisation you mention is a conformal mapping from the plane, hence isothermal.

Answer (score 1):

The formulas of the stereographic projection give $\langle \bar{x}_u,\bar{x}_u\rangle = \langle \bar{x}_v,\bar{x}_v\rangle$ and $\langle \bar{x}_u,\bar{x}_v\rangle = 0$, and the first part of this exercise says $\langle \mathrm{d}N(q_u),\mathrm{d}N(q_u)\rangle = \lambda_p \langle q_u,q_u\rangle$, hence $$\begin{align*}
\langle q_u,q_u\rangle &= \lambda_p^{-1}\langle \mathrm{d}N(q_u),\mathrm{d}N(q_u)\rangle \\
 &= \lambda_p^{-1} \langle (N\circ q)_u,(N\circ q)_u\rangle\\ 
 &= \lambda_p^{-1} \langle \bar{x}_u,\bar{x}_u\rangle \\ 
 &= \lambda_p^{-1} \langle \bar{x}_v,\bar{x}_v\rangle \\
 &= \langle q_v,q_v\rangle
\end{align*}$$
Similarly $$\begin{align*}
\langle q_u,q_v\rangle &= \lambda_p^{-1}\langle \mathrm{d}N(q_u),\mathrm{d}N(q_v)\rangle \\
 &= \lambda_p^{-1} \langle (N\circ q)_u,(N\circ q)_v\rangle\\ 
 &= \lambda_p^{-1} \langle \bar{x}_u,\bar{x}_v\rangle \\ 
 &= 0
\end{align*}$$